# Unable to Publish Composer Bot in Azure

Tags: azure, botframework, bots, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service

I am trying to publish my composer bot app in Azure.

I am referred below links of Microsoft for the same,

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/tutorial/tutorial-introduction
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-publish-bot

I have created a bot with add LUIS as mentioned in the above first link. then I follow the second link but got an error while publishing.
Also, I have created LUIS authoring cognitive service in Azure as mention in first link

Please refer to error text,

```
"{\"name\":\"RequestError\",\"message\":\"Error: read ECONNRESET\",\"cause\":{\"name\":\"Error\",\"message\":\"read ECONNRESET\",\"stack\":\"Error: read ECONNRESET\\n    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:201:27)\"},\"error\":{\"name\":\"Error\",\"message\":\"read ECONNRESET\",\"stack\":\"Error: read ECONNRESET\\n    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:201:27)\"},\"options\":{},\"stack\":\"RequestError: Error: read ECONNRESET\\n    at new RequestError (C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Bot Framework Composer\\\\resources\\\\app.asar.unpacked\\\\extensions\\\\azurePublish\\\\dist\\\\extension.js:7891:13)\\n    at Request.plumbing.callback (C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Bot Framework Composer\\\\resources\\\\app.asar.unpacked\\\\extensions\\\\azurePublish\\\\dist\\\\extension.js:8127:26)\\n    at Request.RP$callback [as callback] (C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Bot Framework Composer\\\\resources\\\\app.asar.unpacked\\\\extensions\\\\azurePublish\\\\dist\\\\extension.js:8098:27)\\n    at self2.callback (C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Bot Framework Composer\\\\resources\\\\app.asar.unpacked\\\\extensions\\\\azurePublish\\\\dist\\\\extension.js:51180:25)\\n    at Request.emit (events.js:210:5)\\n    at Request.onRequestError (C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Bot Framework Composer\\\\resources\\\\app.asar.unpacked\\\\extensions\\\\azurePublish\\\\dist\\\\extension.js:51720:11)\\n    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:210:5)\\n    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (http_client.js:406:9)\\n    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)\\n    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)\\n    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)\\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)\"}"
```

```
"{\"name\":\"StatusCodeError\",\"statusCode\":400,\"message\":\"400 - \\\"{\\\\\\\"error\\\\\\\":{\\\\\\\"code\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"BadArgument\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"message\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"The source completed without providing data to receive.\\\\\\\"}}\\\"\",\"error\":\"{\\\"error\\\":{\\\"code\\\":\\\"BadArgument\\\",\\\"message\\\":\\\"The source completed without providing data to receive.\\\"}}\",\"options\":{},\"response\":{\"statusCode\":400},\"stack\":\"StatusCodeError: 400 - \\\"{\\\\\\\"error\\\\\\\":{\\\\\\\"code\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"BadArgument\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"message\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"The source completed without providing data to receive.\\\\\\\"}}\\\"\\n    at new StatusCodeError (C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Bot Framework Composer\\\\resources\\\\app.asar.unpacked\\\\extensions\\\\azurePublish\\\\dist\\\\extension.js:7904:13)\\n    at Request.plumbing.callback (C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Bot Framework Composer\\\\resources\\\\app.asar.unpacked\\\\extensions\\\\azurePublish\\\\dist\\\\extension.js:8138:28)\\n    at Request.RP$callback [as callback] (C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Bot Framework Composer\\\\resources\\\\app.asar.unpacked\\\\extensions\\\\azurePublish\\\\dist\\\\extension.js:8098:27)\\n    at Request.self2.callback (C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Bot Framework Composer\\\\resources\\\\app.asar.unpacked\\\\extensions\\\\azurePublish\\\\dist\\\\extension.js:51180:25)\\n    at Request.emit (events.js:210:5)\\n    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Bot Framework Composer\\\\resources\\\\app.asar.unpacked\\\\extensions\\\\azurePublish\\\\dist\\\\extension.js:51928:13)\\n    at Request.emit (events.js:210:5)\\n    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Bot Framework Composer\\\\resources\\\\app.asar.unpacked\\\\extensions\\\\azurePublish\\\\dist\\\\extension.js:51859:15)\\n    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:299:28)\\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:215:7)\\n    at endReadableNT (stream_readable.js:1183:12)\\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)\"}"
```

```
"StatusCodeError - 400 - \"{\\\"error\\\":{\\\"code\\\":\\\"BadArgument\\\",\\\"message\\\":\\\"The source completed without providing data to receive.\\\"}}\""
```

Please refer to error screenshots,

[image]

[image]

Please help me with the same as soon as possible.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you post this issue? https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/7480

Comment: yes if You have any solution then  Plz Reply

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site. Do you have a question?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Answer (score 0):

From your publish log, it looks like some of the information/details in your bot framework connection profile are not correct.
This is the .json file
To fix this you should update the information with correct details from your azure bot.